# Kivy Launcher for Python 3

Tags: python, android, kivy

Recently I followed a Kivy tutorial, and I made a calculator. I then wanted to use it on my phone, so I used Kivy Launcher. The problem is, it only uses Python 2, which for some reason, didn't have support for Unicode characters. Also, a lot of the syntax was very different, so I had to change a lot of the code. Just so I could test it out on my phone.

Is there a Python 3 version for the Kivy Launcher? I've seen things like https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1638 but how do you build it? I've ran setup.py and I got a .egg file. What do I do with it? Do I have to make an APK using python-for-android or buildozer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out some ways to achieve what I wanted.

- Get Pydroid 3. Install kivy using Pip and just run it.
- Use buildozer to build the Kivy Launcher. Then I can test out some code without building it all.
- Use VirtualBox to build. Download a version of Ubuntu/Lubuntu and build the APK.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, a lot of the syntax was very different

I think it would be more accurate to say that a small amount of the syntax was somewhat different.

> The problem is, it only uses Python 2, which for some reason, didn't have support for Unicode characters

Python 2 did have support for unicode characters, although the subtleties around how they're handled are one of the real differences between Python 2 and 3.

> Is there a Python 3 version for the Kivy Launcher?

It's possible to build a Python 3 version of the old launcher, or the new one that you've found. However, in both cases if you can build the launcher you could also just build a standalone apk, so you probably may as well follow the instructions to build your own app with buildozer.

> I've ran setup.py and I got a .egg file. What do I do with it? Do I have to make an APK using python-for-android or buildozer?

It sounds like you've built a desktop package for the launcher, if you want to build an apk you must indeed use those projects.

Comment: The whole point of the kivy launcher was that I wanted to test some code, because I can't get Java JDK tools for Buildozer. Is there not an APK for the github repo yet? Or is the app on play store going to be updated?

Comment: The app on the play store may one day be updated, but the launcher isn't very actively maintained and there's no ETA for it. I think pydroid3 may let you achieve the same thing.

Comment: I've tried pydroid, and it's quite good. I just wish that I could build with Buildozer easily, because for some reason I can't build.